# What is "silo dependency"?

Tags: rabbitmq, dependencies, silo

When I learn about RabbitMQ's history, I noticed this statement in one of their articles:

> ... the reduction of change and maintenance costs through the separation of integration concerns,  removal of **silo dependency**, and freedom from language and platform lock-in ...

From rabbitmq.com 《Launch of RabbitMQ Open Source Enterprise Messaging》, Feb, 2007.

I googled "silo dependency" but I didn't get any useful results. And this word(**silo dependency**) also sounds different from "Dependency Injection".

Comment: In this context, I believe "silo" means something like "_any management system that is unable to operate with any other system_" - quote taken from [here](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/I/information_silo.html). That whole Rabbit paragraph is a collection of somewhat vague [buzzwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword_bingo).